# Java Spring Boot & Hibernate - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

estoy queriendo hacer un To-Do list usando SpringBoot con Hibernate, y tengo el siguiente problema: cuando quiero hacer un request POST para crear nuevas tareas en la base de datos que el usuario ingresa, obtengo el error 500 a la hora de fijarme en la consola para revisar por qué no me guarda las tareas en la base de datos. Sé y reconozco que esto es porque hay un error del lado del servidor pero no me logro dar cuenta en qué parte me estoy equivocando... esto serian las clases java

```
    package com.cursojava.curso.models;
    import lombok.Getter;
    import lombok.Setter;
    import javax.persistence.*;

    @Entity

    @Table(name = "tareas")

    public class Tarea {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    
    @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "id")
   
    private Long id;

    @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "tarea")
    private String tarea;

    public Tarea() {

    }

    public Tarea(Long id, String tarea) {
        this.id = id;
        this.tarea = tarea;
    }
```

```
    package com.cursojava.curso.dao;
    import com.cursojava.curso.models.Tarea;
    import de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2;
    import de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2Factory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
    import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaDelete;
    import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
    import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaUpdate;
    import javax.persistence.metamodel.Metamodel;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    
    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class TareaDaoImpl implements TareaDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Tarea> getTareas() {
        String query = "FROM Tarea";
        return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void eliminar(Long id) {
        Tarea tarea = entityManager.find(Tarea.class, id);
        entityManager.remove(tarea);
    }

}
```

```
    package com.cursojava.curso.controllers;
    import com.cursojava.curso.dao.TareaDao;
    import com.cursojava.curso.models.Tarea;
    import de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2;
    import de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2Factory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    @RestController
    public class TareaController {

    @Autowired
    private TareaDao tareaDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "api/tareas", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void registrarTarea(@PathVariable String t) {
        Tarea tarea = new Tarea();
        tarea.setTarea(t);
        tareaDao.registrar(tarea);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "api/tareas", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Tarea> getTareas() {
        return tareaDao.getTareas();
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "api/tareas/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void eliminar(@PathVariable Long id) {
        tareaDao.eliminar(id);
    }
}
```

y este el codigo javascript

```
    async function registrarTarea() {
    let tarea = document.getElementById('txtTarea').value;
    const request = await fetch('api/tareas', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        /*JSON.stringify lo que hace es agarrar cualquier
        objeto de JavaScript y lo convierte a un string de JSON*/
        body: JSON.stringify(tarea)
    });
}
```

STACKTRACE:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.cursojava:curso >-------------------------
[INFO] Building curso 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.0:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ curso >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ curso ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1878 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ curso ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ curso ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\computadora\Desktop\Escri\curso\curso\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ curso ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.0:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ curso <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.0:run (default-cli) @ curso ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.0)

2021-11-22 11:09:13.522  INFO 1576 --- [           main] com.cursojava.curso.CursoApplication     : Starting CursoApplication using Java 11.0.3 on computadora-PC with PID 1576 (C:\Users\computadora\Desktop\Escri\curso\curso\target\classes started by computadora in C:\Users\computadora\Desktop\Escri\curso\curso)
2021-11-22 11:09:13.522  INFO 1576 --- [           main] com.cursojava.curso.CursoApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-11-22 11:09:14.473  INFO 1576 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-11-22 11:09:14.505  INFO 1576 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 8 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-11-22 11:09:15.597  INFO 1576 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-11-22 11:09:15.659  INFO 1576 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-11-22 11:09:15.659  INFO 1576 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
2021-11-22 11:09:15.893  INFO 1576 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-11-22 11:09:15.893  INFO 1576 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2293 ms
2021-11-22 11:09:16.330  INFO 1576 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-11-22 11:09:16.548  INFO 1576 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-11-22 11:09:16.673  INFO 1576 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-11-22 11:09:16.907  INFO 1576 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.1.Final
2021-11-22 11:09:17.469  INFO 1576 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-11-22 11:09:17.671  INFO 1576 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
2021-11-22 11:09:19.450  INFO 1576 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-11-22 11:09:19.465  INFO 1576 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-11-22 11:09:19.606  WARN 1576 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-11-22 11:09:20.183  INFO 1576 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-11-22 11:09:20.199  INFO 1576 --- [           main] com.cursojava.curso.CursoApplication     : Started CursoApplication in 7.781 seconds (JVM running for 8.616)
2021-11-22 11:09:51.195  INFO 1576 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-11-22 11:09:51.195  INFO 1576 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-11-22 11:09:51.196  INFO 1576 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2021-11-22 11:10:26.237  WARN 1576 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException: Required URI template variable 't' for method parameter type String is not present]
```

Comment: Lo suyo sería que pusieses el stack trace del error en java, porque ahí te indica exactamente ***qué*** error tienes.

Comment: Como comenta @Benito-B, el error 500 es un error no controlado y sin la traza del error no es posible darte una solución.

Comment: ahí agregué el stacktrace

Comment: Ya lo solucioné. Por la última línea del stack trace me hizo concluir en cambiar los parámetros del método registarTarea por @RequestBody Tarea (y borrar la creación y seteo del objeto local tarea) tarea, el error persistía pero usando el stack trace nuevamente me ayudo a darme cuenta que no tenía declarado los constructores necesarios en la clase Tarea. Moraleja? Siempre debo apoyarme en el stack trace de java...

Answer (score 0):

Creo que hay varios errores en el código que hay  que ir resolviendo paso a paso.

Estas usando `@PathVariable` en los params, sin embargo no le estás diciendo como se compone la URL con ese parametro.

Eso te lo indica en la ultima línea del stack trace:

`11:10:26.237  WARN 1576 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException: Required URI template variable 't' for method parameter type String is not present]`

Un ejemplo con `@PathVariable` es esto:

```java
@GetMapping("/foos/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public String getFooById(@PathVariable String id) {
   return "ID: " + id;
}
```

Ahí lo que haces es decirle como se compone la URL que te lleva a ese endpoint (ej, `http://localhost:8080/foo/1`), es decir la URL va a contener el id de la instacia/objeto SIEMPRE. Tené en cuenta que podes construir la URL en base a la necesidad, otro ej: `foo/{id}/update` que nos da como resultado: `http://localhost:8080/foo/1/update`

Después tenés `@RequestParams`, los request params agregan `queryParams` a la URL. Mismo ejemplo anterior pero con request params sería algo así:

```java
@GetMapping("/foos")
@ResponseBody
public String getFooByIdUsingQueryParam(@RequestParam String id) {
    return "ID: " + id;
}
```

El resultado de esto ultimo es la siguiente URL: `http://localhost:8080/foos?id=abc`

Elije usar `@PathVariable` o `@RequestParams` en base a la necesidad de tu proyecto, generalmente se usa `@PathVariable` con los ids y cuando se trata de editar un único elemento.

Recomiendo leer más aquí:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-pathvariable

Prueba estos cambios, y si sigues teniendo errores (que creo que sí seguirás teniéndolos) publica el nuevo stack trace para poder seguir guíandote paso a paso.

Answer (score -2):

El repositorio no va asi.
Te pongo un ejemplo de repositiorio de Srping.

```
@Repository
public interface HospitalRepository extends JpaRepository<Hospital, String> {

}
```

Lo que tienes como repositorio serian los Servicios.
Aqui tienes un ejemplo https://github.com/carlos033/ServidorRest

Comment: si bien se acostumbra utilizar spring-data con JpaRepository como en tu ejemplo, el ejemplo de la pregunta es correcto porque esta inyectando el entityManager con el cual puedes realizar las operaciones como lo harías con hibernate.